# Python: how to work with list to have unique values

Tags: python

The problem that I have is the following: I get from a process, a set of values:

```
t=903
a=432
c=335
```

And these values goes in a dictionary, which assign different sequences of t, a and c to different keys

```
{key1} : (t1 a1 c1, t2 a2 c2, ...tn an cn)
{key2} : (t1 a1 c1, t2 a2 c2, ...tn an cn)
```

What I would like, is to not add a triplet of values to a key, if the first value (say t), is already present. Basically I would use "t" variable as unique factor for my triplet. This only apply for each key, so I don't mind if I have the same value on key 2...key n; the important is that each key has an unique value of t, and that the 3 values are written in the dictionary only if the value of "t" is unique.

I tried this:

```
for triplets in dict[key1]:
    if not t in triplets:
        dict[key1].append(t,a,c)
```

But this seems to not be working. Am I cycling incorrectly trough the dictionary? Should I use a different structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create another level; each value a dictionary keyed on `t`:

```
tripplets = dict.setdefault(key1, {})
if t not in triplets:
    triplets[t] = (t, a, c)
```

This produces:

```
{
    'key1': {'t1': (t1, a1, c2),
             't2': (t2, a2, c2)},
    ...
}
```

so only add `(t?, a?, c?)` if `t?` is not already a key in the `dict[key1]` dictionary.

You could also replace your triple-value tuples with a custom class that implements `__eq__` and `__hash__` to be considered equal if their `t` value is equal:

```
class Entry(object):
    __slots__ = ('t', 'a', 'c')  # save some memory
    def __init__(self, t, a, c):
        self.t = t
        self.a = a
        self.c = c
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Entry): return NotImplemented
        return self.t == other.t
    def __hash__(self):
        return id(self.t)
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<{0}({1[0]!r}, {1[1]!r}, {1[2]!r})>'.format(type(self).__name__, self)
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return getattr(self, 'tac'[index])
```

then use sets in your dictionary:

```
dict(key1, set()).add(Entry(t, a, c))
```

If however, you sometimes wanted to keep `t` unique, and `a` or `c` at other times, there is nothing for it but to do an actual search. Use the [`any()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) to bail out early if a match has been found:

```
triplets = dict.setdefault(key1, [])
if not any(triplet[0] == t for triplet in triplets):
    # no such t value found
    triplets.append((t, a, c))
```

Comment: Thanks, so basically I need to have another dictionary inside the dictionary? That complicate a bit the things; since if I want to use for example a or c instead of t, then I have to change the whole structure. I was hoping that it was possible to search trough a list, which is used in a dictionary.

Comment: @newbiez: then you'll just have to do a search each time.

Comment: @MartijnPieters or write a more complicated `Entry` object or manager that allows you to specify the comparison item per-instance.

Comment: @aruisdante: no, you cannot alter the `__hash__` behaviour once you store it in a set. That'd break the set hash table completely.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh absolutely. I was merely suggesting it would be possible to allow for selection of which element to use as the comparison without having to alter the `Entry` code every time. You still need to have homogenous collections of those comparisons, not half of one and half of another. Though admittedly since there would be no way to actually enforce you to do so without adding a bunch of extra logic around the set/dict, it wouldn't be the safest thing to do.

Comment: Much appreciated for the explanation. This answer and the one from @aruisdante are both good!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a whole lot like... a second dictionary! You could implement your data-structure as follows:

```
from collections import defaultdict

items = defaultdict(dict)

def add_entry(items, key, t, a, c):
    values = items[key]
    if t not in values:
        values[t] = (a,c)

def get_entry(items, key):
    values = items[key]
    entry  = []
    for t, (a,c) in values.iteritems():
        entry.extend((t,a,c))
    return entry
```

Usage:

```
>>> add_entry(items, "test", 1, 2, 3)
>>> get_entry(items, "test")
[1, 2, 3]
>>> add_entry(items, "test", 2, 2, 3)
>>> get_entry(items, "test")
[1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3]
>>> add_entry(items, "test", 1, 6, 7)
>>> get_entry(items, "test")
[1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3]
>>> add_entry(items, "test2", 1, 2, 3)
>>> get_entry(items, "test2")
[1, 2, 3]
```

Replace `entry.extend((t,a,c))` with `entry.append((t,a,c))` if you want to get back a list of tuples rather than just a list of values.

And of course you could encapsulate this datastructure and the methods that operate on it into a class for better usability if you'd like, like so:

```
class EntryManager(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._items = defaultdict(dict)

    def add_entry(self, key, t, a, c):
        values = self._items[key]
        if t not in values:
            values[t] = (a,c)

    def get_entry(self, key):
        values = self._items[key]
        entry  = []
        for t, (a,c) in values.iteritems():
            entry.extend((t,a,c))
        return entry
```

Comment: Thanks, defaultdict are quite nice. they are both working; but I went for this solution